# MySQL: Identify duplicates and replace values - beginner

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

**Platform:** MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE **SQL:** 5.5.57

I'm having trouble creating the proper statement for following task:

Let's say we have a table 'departments'

```
| id | name | superior_dep_id |
_______________________________
  1  | SM   |  null          
  2  | SMT  |  1      
  3  | SMTE |  2 
  4  | SMI  |  1      
  5  | SM   |  null
```

and i've just added a new department 'SM' which will replace the old department, in terms of validity only, so the old one still remains unchanged.

Now i'd need identify all departments, which contain the old `departments.id` at `departments.superior_dep_id` and replace them with the new `departments.id = 5`.

```
| id | name | superior_dep_id |
_______________________________
  1  | SM   |  null          
  2  | SMT  |  1      <--- 5
  3  | SMTE |  2 
  4  | SMI  |  1      <--- 5
  5  | SM   |  null   <--- INSERT INTO 
                           departments(id, name, superior_dep_id) 
                           VALUES(5, SM, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save the old ID in a variable before you insert the new department. Then use an `UPDATE` statement that sets `superior_dep_id` to the new ID where the value is the old ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I guess you will have to indentify the last departments.id inserted by name, skipping the last one you inserted:

```
select departments.id from departments where name = 'SM' and departments.id <> 5 ORDER BY departments.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

After you get the departments.id (which will be 1), you can update the fields:

```
update departments set superior_dep_id = 5 where superior_dep_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped me alot. How can i accept this answer?

Comment: Glad I could help. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.